# Python os.listdir() keeps skipping over some files?

Tags: python, shell, scripting

I have written a Python script for writing out all the file names in a given directory to a file for processing, and it works perfectly on my machine. But when I try to run it on the target machine, it skips some of the files. Here's a shell of the code I am using:

```
for line in os.listdir(d):
    f.write(line + "\n")
```

As I said, this works as advertised on my system, but not on the target system. The data is the same; I transferred it from the target system to mine for preliminary testing while writing the script, and I've inspected both data sources to verify that nothing got lost in the transfer. Output from my system looks like:

```
filename.f0000
filename.f0001
filename.f0002
filename.f0003
...
```

But output from the target system looks like:

```
filename.f0000
filename.f0003
filename.f0008
filename.f0017
...
```

I am on a 64-bit Windows PC running Cygwin, and it has Python version 2.7.5 installed. The target system is a Cray XK7 running OpenSuse, and it has Python version 2.6.8 installed.

Could this be a difference between the two versions of Python, or rather the two different operating systems?

Comment: have you checked all files? the result of listdir is not ordered.

Comment: Try upgrading the target system to 2.7.5 to take that out of the question. If that doesn't help any, then it may be the target system OS

Comment: @Daniel is there a way to get an ordered list, instead?

Comment: @heinst unfortunately, that is out of the question. The target system is a government-owned research system; I only have a monthly allotment of hours on it.

Comment: @JonathanLandrum then downgrade your test machine

Comment: You can try to use the built in sorted method, eg `for line in sorted(os.listdir(d))`

Comment: @Mariatta that worked perfectly, thank you! Why was my work machine sorting output but the target machine wasn't? I ended up having to use `sorted()` statements in a couple of other places, too.

Comment: I believe it's because each file system has their own way of ordering and indexing files.

Comment: I didn't expect that, given `ls` sorts the data correctly on both machines. Either way, thanks to you and @Daniel for the idea of sorting the output. I should have asked this two hours ago; would have saved me a lot of headache. Convert your comment into an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: The order of the results in `os.listdir()` is generally whatever the raw order of directory entries is in the underlying file system; that order depends on the file system implementation and can depend on the order that the files were created in (among other factors).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can try to use the built in sorted method, eg

```
for line in sorted(os.listdir(d)):
    f.write(line + "\n")
```

Here's some more information from python documentation that you might find helpful:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

**os.listdir(path)**

> Return a list containing the names of the entries in the directory
>   given by path. **The list is in arbitrary order**. It does not include the
>   special entries '.' and '..' even if they are present in the
>   directory.